# MapBox GL load markers dynamically on 'moved' event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I'm working on a map style app using MapBox GL API (v0.39.1) and RoR, and I can't find a solution for my problem. I will try to explain as clear as possible, providing code examples.

Lets say we have 10.000 locations. For each location, I want to display a custom marker with a specific image.
Of course we can't load the map with 10.000 locations and images, because it will lag and crash the browser.

The solution is to display only locations that are visible on the maps view point (basically only locations visible in the maps bounds). And do AJAX calls to fetch new locations when the map is 'mooved' or 'zoomed'.

```
# The code use for the solution
map.on 'load', (e) ->
  # Creat markers visible in the maps view point
  mapbox.setContent()

  # Add 'mooved' event to the map
  map.on('moveend', mapbox.move_event)


mapbox.setContent = ->
  $.ajax
    url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/api/map_data"
    type: "GET"
    # Send map coordinates
    data:
      sw_lng: map.getBounds()._sw.lng,
      ne_lng: map.getBounds()._ne.lng,
      ne_lat: map.getBounds()._ne.lat,
      sw_lat: map.getBounds()._sw.lat
    success: (data) ->
      window.locations_data = data

      for i in data.features
        # Simply adds a new marker to the map with custom image from the GeoJSON
        mapbox.createMarkers(i)

mapbox.move_event = ->
  mapbox.setContent()
```

So each time the map 'moveend' a AJAX call is sent to the server with the maps parameters and gets locations that are in the maps view point.

```
# location.rb Location model, each location represents a marker on the map
def self.build_geojson(sw_lng, ne_lng, ne_lat, sw_lat)
  locations = self.where("longitude > ? AND longitude < ? AND latitude < ? AND latitude > ?", sw_lng, ne_lng, ne_lat, sw_lat)

  # Function that builds the GeoJSON from the locations
  return build(locations)
```

The scenarios is the following:

1. Map loaded, displaying 130 locations.
2. User moves the map, AJAX is sent and now there should be displayed 150 locations.
3. Out of the 150 locations, 90 are already displayed from the initial load (130)

How can I only remove the 40 (130 - 90) markers? Because I don't want to delete all the initial 130 markers. Then add 150 markers. I didn't find any 'good' way to do this.

I need to be very smart how I approach this problem, because MapBox GL with inefficient code is eating resources, memory, CPU, etc.

Please help and thank you!

Comment: Why don't you want to "delete all the initial 130 markers. Then add 150 markers. " Did you try it?

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ that was the only solution I found, I thought that there is a better one. I'm not that good with JS HTML tricks.

Comment: but what's the downside? was it slow? bad UX?